# WCF Multipart Custom Class

Tags: android, wcf, request, multipart

I send a POST request from an Android App using the ION library. The request has some multipart parameters and an attachment file.

Something like this:

```
            .setMultipartParameter("Message", message)
            .setMultipartParameter("TextFileName", textFileName)
            .setMultipartParameter("TextFileContentBase64Encoded", TextFileContentBase64Encoded)
            .setMultipartFile("AttachementFile", fileName)
```

The problem is that server side(WCF), we have a custom class used for parsing this request that has a Stream for the attachment file, and 3 Strings for other parameters.  From my understanding, WCF limits you. You can't parse a custom class that has a Stream and other parameters. You either have a Stream or you have other params.

The question is how can you parse a incoming request that has a stream and other parameters in WCF?

Thanks!